# ionic2 ngx-translate error: (alias) new TranslateHttpLoader(prefix?: string, suffix?: string): TranslateHttpLoader import TranslateHttpLoader

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm following the instructions in [this tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/) to make translation, but I have this error:

```
[ts] Expected 0-2 arguments, but got 3.
(alias) new TranslateHttpLoader(prefix?: string, suffix?: string): 
TranslateHttpLoader
import TranslateHttpLoader
```

in the code:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

and if I removed http from `TranslateHttpLoader` method I got this error:

```
ncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.http.get is not a function 
TypeError: this.http.get is not a function
```

I don't know what to do, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the   *./assets/i18n/*, *.json* from the method call and it will search for the files on that place by default.